# how to get data from ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have a code to request rest web service:

```
<script>
    var respone='';
    $('.inn').on('change',function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            url:url,
            success: function(data){
                var json=JSON.parse(data);
                respone=data;
                console.log(respone);
            },
            error:function(e)
            {
                console.log(e);
            }

        });
        alert(respone);
        console.log(respone)

    })
</script>
```

Rest web service works fine and it returns json data. Ajax also returning some data but not in console. Is it possible to get ajax response and preview it in console?

Comment: Is it `jsonp` or `JSON`?

Comment: for jsonp you need callback

Comment: Please put a `console.log(data)` just before the line `var json=JSON.parse(data);` in `success` callback, and post the results here.

Comment: AJAX is `async` and hence you can log response once AJAX succeeds..i.e in `success` callback

Comment: I have already put console.log(data) but it returned nothing

Comment: You said "Ajax also returning some data but not in console..."

How do you know that data is being returned by the ajax call?

I ask because if indeed something is being returned then console.log(respone) should log something to the console indeed.

Also are you sure you are not seeing the error log? Try something like:
    `console.log("success", respone); // in the success block`
    `console.log("failure", e); // in the failure block`

This will make sure you are seeing the right response.

Comment: I used Chrome DevTools->network->response. There is json data.

Comment: In error, I got following: Object {readyState: 0, responseText: undefined, status: 0, statusText: "error"}

Answer (score 0):

Check the following lines:

**dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html))
Type: String**
The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and anything else will be returned as a string). The available types (and the result passed as the first argument to your success callback) are:

**"xml":** Returns a XML document that can be processed via jQuery.

**"html":** Returns HTML as plain text; included script tags are evaluated when inserted in the DOM.

**"script":** Evaluates the response as JavaScript and returns it as plain text. Disables caching by appending a query string parameter, _=[TIMESTAMP], to the URL unless the cache option is set to true. Note: This will turn POSTs into GETs for remote-domain requests.

**"json":** Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript object. Cross-domain "json" requests are converted to "jsonp" unless the request includes jsonp: false in its request options. The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown. As of jQuery 1.9, an empty response is also rejected; the server should return a response of null or {} instead. (See json.org for more information on proper JSON formatting.)

**"jsonp":** Loads in a JSON block using JSONP. Adds an extra "?callback=?" to the end of your URL to specify the callback. Disables caching by appending a query string parameter, "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the URL unless the cache option is set to true.

**"text":** A plain text string.

[Complete Reference](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

And you can console your response like:

```
success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
}
```